# graphite can't find auth_user.frm

Tags: django, graphite

I have graphite 0.10.0 running on CentOS 7.  I had the screens populating, and data being imported from Icinga, however, when I went to add a new user, I got an error, and now graphite won't start in Apache.  The error I get is long, but the key appears to be :

```
OperationalError: (1017, "Can't find file: './graphite/auth_user.frm' 
(errno: 13)")
```

The head of the traceback is:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=7002): Target WSGI script '/usr/share/graphite/graphite-web.wsgi' 
cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Dec 29 21:30:48.254942 2016] [:error] [pid 7002] [client 172.72.77.141:52770] 
mod_wsgi (pid=7002): Exception occurred processing WSGI script
 '/usr/share/graphite/graphite-web.wsgi'.
```

I know the file exists, in `/var/lib/mysql/graphite/`, and apache has permissions.  I modified the `STORAGE_DIR` to `/var/lib/mysql/graphite` in the `local_settings.py`, but I am not sure if that was the right variable.

Does anyone know the variable to fix, or what might be incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

After leaving it and coming back this morning, I found the issue.  The graphite database was owned by Apache, and it should have been MySQL, I am not sure when it got changed, I must have misread an instruction somewhere, but the error was actually thrown by MariaDB, and changing the owner back instantly resolved the issue.